# In Three.js, using blendSrc: THREE.OneMinusDstAlphaFactor results in nothing being displayed

Tags: three.js, blend

I am a beginner in three.js. When I set the blendSrc to THREE.OneMinusDstAlphaFactor in a plane mesh material, the mesh is not displayed. Here is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="container"></div>
        <script type="importmap">
            {
                "imports": {
                    "three": "../build/three.module.js",
                    "three/addons/": "./jsm/"
                }
            }
        </script>

        <script type="module">

            import * as THREE from 'three';

            import Stats from 'three/addons/libs/stats.module.js';

            let container, stats;

            let camera, scene, renderer;

            let mesh1, mesh2;

            init();
            animate();

            function init() {

                container = document.getElementById( 'container' );

                //

                camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 27, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 3500 );
                camera.position.z = 5;

                scene = new THREE.Scene();

                var geometry1 = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(1, 1); 
                var geometry2 = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(1, 1); 
  
                var material1 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial(
                    { 
                        color: 0x00ff00, 
                        transparent: true, 
                        opacity: 0.5,
                    }
                );
                var material2 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial(
                    { 
                        color: 0xff0000, 
                        transparent: true, 
                        opacity: 0.5,
                        blending: THREE.CustomBlending,
                        
                        blendSrc: THREE.OneMinusDstAlphaFactor,
                        blendDst: THREE.OneFactor,

                    }
                );

                mesh1 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry1, material1 );
                mesh1.position.x = 0.25;

                mesh2 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry2, material2 );
                mesh2.position.x = -0.25;
                mesh2.position.z = 0.25;

                scene.add( mesh1 );
                scene.add( mesh2 );

                //

                renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
                renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
                container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

                //

                stats = new Stats();
                container.appendChild( stats.dom );

                //

                window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize );

            }

            function onWindowResize() {

                camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
                camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

            }

            //

            function animate() {

                requestAnimationFrame( animate );

                render();
                stats.update();

            }

            function render() {

                renderer.render( scene, camera );

            }

        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zX4lO.png)

According to the formula: C_result = C_source * F_source + C_destination * F_destination (ref: https://learnopengl.com/Advanced-OpenGL/Blending), my expected result is that the overlapped area will be displayed as C_result = (1 - Alpha_dst) * (1, 0, 0) + 1 * (0, 1, 0) = 0.5 * (1, 0, 0) + 1 * (0, 1, 0) = (0.5, 1, 0). Did I misunderstand something?